# How to get scrolling speed of iOS WebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, web, webview, safari

My problem is that the [`window.onscroll` event](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) of a WebView of iOS is generated when the page stops moving and redraws.

I want to get the speed of scroll event, so that I can lazily load some pics to my page when the scroll is "slow enough"（but at this time，the scroll event is still going).

I found that `onscroll` event would be generated when the page is moving in *Safari*, but it is generated when the page stops moving in WebView.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for you http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/

Comment: en,thanks very much,and i decided use 'settimeout' to solve the problem,and the difference between  safari and webview is caused by ios8,what i learn from the link of urs